# вызов функции из мейна

Tags: c#

Что то не могу понять что делаю не так. Как вызвать `After` в `main`
Нужно, чтобы отображались строки `af` и `asd` в `main`

Нужно примерно вот так чтобы в `main` было:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(af + Environment.NewLine + asd);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
public static void After(string af, string asd)
    {
        if (!af.EndsWith("123"))
        {
            if (asd.StartsWith("456"))
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `static void Main(.....bla bla) { After("string1", "string 2"); }`

Comment: @MichaelVaysman а что с ним не так?

Comment: `After(af, asd);` прописал вот так, подчеркивает `af`, `asd`

Comment: Так они же у вас в Main не определены :)

Comment: заработало вот так: `static void Main(string[] args,string af,string asd)` только почему, я не понял..

Comment: Во первых, в Main не добавляют в ручную параметры. Давайте так, вы хотите параметры в командной строке давать или считывать откуда-то?

Answer (score 2):

Можно например вот так:

```
static string af="123456";
static string asd="456789";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(af + Environment.NewLine + asd);
    After(af, asd);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void After(string af, string asd)
{
    if (!af.EndsWith("123"))
    {
        if (asd.StartsWith("456"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Или, например вы передаете параметры при запуске exe, типа `C:\myProgram.exe 123456 456789`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string af = args[1];
    string asd = args[2];
    Console.WriteLine(af + Environment.NewLine + asd);
    After(af, asd);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
public static void After(string af, string asd)
{
    if (!af.EndsWith("123"))
    {
        if (asd.StartsWith("456"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```